# Connecting Matlab to a mysql database server

Tags: mysql, matlab

My project deals with connecting an online Mysql database server to MATLAB (R2013b) However I don't have the Matlab database toolbox in my Matlab license. Any suggestions on how can I connect Matlab to the database server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8663-mysql-database-connector), a free tool available from the MATLAB Central File Exchange. There are lots of other possibilities as well, if you just google for "MATLAB MySQL".

But trust me: the easiest thing to do is to just buy Database Toolbox. If you put a dollar value on your time per hour, then unless your time is worth almost nothing you will spend less by buying the toolbox than you will by trying other ways.